# SSIS 2008 Transactionoption

Tags: ssis

i have set the TransactionOption as Required in my SSIS package. But the package fails. The error shown is some MSDTC error. I am not able to get it. is there any settings to be changed or done in the machine or server we are deploying/running/working the package ? So wat all steps should we have to follow for setting Transaction in  a package.

Comment: Can You check in event log? Is MSDTC started and configured properly?

Answer (score 2):

> "The built-in transaction support in SSIS makes use of the Distributed
>   Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) service which must be running.  MSDTC
>   also allows you to perform distributed transactions; e.g. updating a
>   SQL Server database and an Oracle database in the same transaction."

[How To Use Transactions in SQL Server Integration Services SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)

I hope this helps

Comment: Hows the MSDTC configuration done, before applying the TransactionOption ?

Comment: This howto will probably help you. [Utilizing Transactions in SSIS to Rollback After a Failed Import](http://lanestechblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/utilizing-transactions-in-ssis-to.html)